# Passing the JSON params as kwargs in Python

Tags: python, json, elasticsearch

I have some post data of the format

```
d = {
    "filters": [
        {
            "type": "range",
            "question__created_at": "2014-11-10T11:11:55.027Z",
            "exclude_filter": False,

        },
        {
            "type": "terms",
            "question_name": ["AB","CD"]
            "exclude_filter": False,

        }
    ],
    "count": True
}
```

What I am trying to achieve here is the I pick the value of the every filter type from the key "type" of each filter dictionary. And I send the rest of all the fields as kwargs and that will directly be passed to the query that I am appending these filters.

So here is the query that will be appended based on the the number of filters I pass:

```
s = Search(using=es).index(settings.ES_INDEX).doc_type(model)
```

This is the default elasticsearch that is like a match all query on my db.

When I pass the above filter(JSON) and in this case when I have 2 filters passed , below is what my modified query should look like:

```
s = Search(using=es).index(settings.ES_INDEX).doc_type(model)

s = s.filter(
    F('range', question__created_at="2014-11-10T11:11:55.027Z", exclude_filter=True) &
    F('terms', question_name=["AB","CD"], exclude_filter=True))
```

So, depending on any number of filters passed it should dynamically go on to append them with the "s" object

Can anyone help on how I can write a function in python that picks up the filter type separate and rest of it as kwargs so that I can unpack everything directly to the query?

Comment: You mean you have an existing function and you want to call that function with `existing_function('range', **{'question__created_at': '....', 'exclude_filter': False})`?

Comment: Can you please update your question to include a sample of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Also, is the `d = ` really part of the format you are being sent? The rest is valid JSON, just not that specific prefix.

Comment: @MartijnPieters , I just edited my question. Please check if its you're able to get my requirement.

Comment: Your Python syntax is incorrect; `false` is JSON syntax, not Python. Which is why I asked you if your first sample is including the `d =`; perhaps that is actually meant to be Python code?

Comment: Also, is that really how you create filters for the `Search` object? You have both a method (`s.F(...)`) and an instance (`F(...)`). I suspect that isn't quite correct.

Comment: that is not the issue @MartijnPieters I understand that part. I am a little new with python and hence facing problems to create  a function that picks up the type and other values as kwargs and passes to my query. I you could help me write the python logic for that function ?

Comment: That is *an* issue with your post; being able to help you with correct code is important, as it avoids having to go back and forth later on over those details.

Comment: @MartijnPieters  I have managed to execute the queries, the issue here is only with the function. I can manage that search function syntax. that is not an issue

Comment: It is an issue *for people trying to help you*. I am not familiar with the specific library, but if you want me to be effective in helping you, do please correct issues I find in your question. Based on some googling I've corrected your code to something that might actually work in a Python session.

Answer (score 2):

You can dynamically build multiple filters by extracting the `type` key from the dictionary, and applying the remainder to the `F()` filter object. `S.filter()` returns an updated search, so just keep applying the next filter to the object in a loop:

```
for filter in d['filters']:
    type_ = filter.pop('type')
    s = s.filter(type_, **filter)
```

Comment: @AmitP: Note that I am not quite sure what library you are using here; `elasticutils`'s `F()` callable doesn't take positional arguments, for example.

Comment: I am using elasticsearch-dsl